# binding_of_caller REPL not triggering in Better Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, better-errors-gem

I have a Rails application using Better Errors, but the error pages won't load the binding_of_caller interactive shell (REPL). Instead, it still just shows:

```
Tip: add gem "binding_of_caller" to your Gemfile to enable the REPL and local/instance variable inspection.
```

My Gemfile has:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'debugger'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller' #, :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
```

The last part I've tried either commented or uncommented. When attempting "require 'binding_of_caller'" in a Rails console it returns false rather than erroring, implying it has been loaded properly. The Gemfile.lock shows the following versions:

```
rails (4.1.0.rc2)
better_errors (1.1.0)
  coderay (>= 1.0.0)
  erubis (>= 2.6.6)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
  debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
```

What might be wrong? What other code should I provide to find clues as to what went wrong?

Comment: `better_errors` is not dependent on `binding_of_caller`. I'm running it without it. it must be a bug

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, better_errors itself is functioning properly, though the added functionality of live debugging would be much welcomed. Perhaps you're right, maybe I should file a bug report on Github...

Comment: the REPL (live shell) is also working for me. all I had to do was:`gem 'better_errors'` generate a new project with scaffold. then add better_errs gem to see if you get similar results.

Comment: already reported https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/243

Comment: @matanco: that issue appears to be about better_errors not working at all; for me better_errors itself does.

Comment: @Tycho ever figure out this issue?

Comment: @you786: sorry, I don't even recall :(, I stopped doing Ruby quite a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

is set in your config/environments/development.rb

Also, if you are using a sublime editor,you can add:

```
BetterErrors.editor = :sublime if defined? BetterErrors
```

in your config/initializers folder by naming a file "better_errors.rb"

Let me know if this helps?